# Corrupt zip file while download by URL

Tags: c#, .net, zip, webclient

I download 3(2 zip 1 txt file) files from http://download.geonames.org/export/dump/ use WebClient and one of zip file which have size 9 Mb, when i download it have size 215 Mb and corrupt..I try use WebRequest and FileStream class but again have same result..

My methods for alternate WebClient download :

```
private void MyDownloadFile(Uri url, string outputFilePath)
        {
            const int BUFFER_SIZE = 16 * 1024;
            using (var outputFileStream = File.Create(outputFilePath, BUFFER_SIZE))
            {
                var req = WebRequest.Create(url);
                using (var response = req.GetResponse())
                {
                    using (var responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
                    {
                        var buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
                        int bytesRead;
                        do
                        {
                            bytesRead = responseStream.Read(buffer, 0, BUFFER_SIZE);
                            outputFileStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                        } while (bytesRead > 0);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

private void DownloadFile(String Url, String ResultFileName)
        {
            HttpWebRequest wr = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(Url);
            HttpWebResponse ws = (HttpWebResponse)wr.GetResponse();
            Stream str = ws.GetResponseStream();

            byte[] inBuf = new byte[100000];
            int bytesReadTotal = 0;

            FileStream fstr = new FileStream(ResultFileName, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);

            while (true)
            {
                int n = str.Read(inBuf, 0, 100000);
                if ((n == 0) || (n == -1))
                {
                    break;
                }

                fstr.Write(inBuf, 0, n);

                bytesReadTotal += n;
            }

            str.Close();
            fstr.Close();
        }
```

File URL which corrupt while download: http://download.geonames.org/export/dump/allCountries.zip

Anyone, have same problem or can write method for correct upload this zip file?? Or maybe i do something wrong??

Comment: Looking at http://download.geonames.org/export/dump/, `allCountries.zip` *should* be about 208M, not 9M. Are you sure you're downloading the right file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using the WebClient.DownloadFile method ([WebClient.DownloadFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ez801hhe.aspx))

```
using (var wc = new WebClient())
{
  wc.DownloadFile(Url, ResultFileName);
}
```